# Passing delegates with generic type as method parameters in C#

Tags: c#, generics, methods, delegates, parameter-passing

I have a problem with delegates and generic type. I'm experimenting with the delegates and I ran into something I'm stuck with.

So I created a function where the programmer can specify a Serialization function and a Deserialization function. Later, this class will use those functions to serialize/deserialize data. For this, I created a delegate for both and a method that receives a Serialization delegate and a Deserialization delegate.

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public delegate string SerializeAction<T>(T _object);
    public delegate T DeserializeAction<T>(string data);
    public static SerializeAction serializeAction;
    public static DeserializeAction deserializeAction;

    public static void SetupConverter<T>(SerializeAction<T> _serializeFunction, DeserializeAction<T> _deserializeFunction)
    {
       serializeAction = _serializeFunction;
       deserializeAction = _deserializeFunction;
    }        
}
```

However, I get syntax error at the declaration of `serializeAction` and `deserializeAction`.

> Using the generic type 'SerializeAction' requires 1 type arguments

If I use `SerializeAction<T> serializeAction`, then it can't find `T`.
And there is another error. I created two functions to test the `SetupConverter` method.

```
class DataJSONConverter
{
    public static string Serialize<T>(T _object) { return JsonSerializer.Serialize(_object); }
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string data) { return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(data); }
}
```

These are two simple functions that use `System.Text.Json` to serialize. After this, I tried to call  the setup method, but got syntax error again.

```
SetupConverter(DataJSONConverter.Serialize, DataJSONConverter.Deserialize);
```

The following error shows up:

> The type arguments for method 'SetupConverter(SerializeAction, DeserializeAction)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

So what I want to create in a nutshell: I have `MyClass` and it has the `SetupConverter` method. By passing two functions as arguments, the programmer can specify the converting functions. Later, if the programmer calls one of the methods of `MyClass` that uses convertion (such as this example), then the specified functions will be used.

```
public static void DoSomething<T>(T _object)
{
    string result = serializeAction(_object);
    T _object2 = deserializeAction<T>(result);
}
```

What did I miss about delegates or generic type? What are those syntax errors?
I truly hope that someone can help me with this, I'd be really grateful.

Comment: `T` would need to be declared at the class level i.e. `public static class MyClass<T>`.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the answers solved my problem, I was keep running into the "generic field" problem that **Sweeper** mentioned. However, I learned a lot from the answers, so thank you very much! I reconsidered the structure of my program and replaced the "delegate solution". If someone who wants to achieve some mechanic like this, just tell me and I'll do my best to explain my solution! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a class with two generic methods `Method1<T>` and `Method2<T>`, then nothing guarantees that the `T` is actually the same type. The caller decides.

If you want a generic class that works with one type only, your *class* need to be generic, not your methods.

```
public static class MyClass<T>
{
    public static Func<T, string> serializeAction;
    public static Func<string, T> deserializeAction;

    public static void SetupConverter(Func<T, string> _serializeFunction, Func<string, T> _deserializeFunction)
    {
       serializeAction = _serializeFunction;
       deserializeAction = _deserializeFunction;
    }        
}
```

You should probably use the `Func<T>` type instead of delegates.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for generic *fields*, but that doesn't exist in C#. As a workaround, you should make `MyClass` generic. Classes can be generic too!

```
// this should be generic
public static class MyClass<T>
{

    // these should not be generic
    public delegate string SerializeAction(T _object);
    public delegate T DeserializeAction(string data);
    private static SerializeAction serializeAction;
    private static DeserializeAction deserializeAction;


    // this should not be generic
    public static void SetupConverter(SerializeAction<T> _serializeFunction, DeserializeAction<T> _deserializeFunction)
    {
       serializeAction = _serializeFunction;
       deserializeAction = _deserializeFunction;
    }

    // this should not be generic
    public static void DoSomething(T _object)
    {
        string result = serializeAction(_object);
        T _object2 = deserializeAction<T>(result);
     }
}
```

So rather than

```
MyClass.DoSomething<Foo>(someFoo);
```

You would do:

```
MyClass<Foo>.DoSomething(someFoo);
```